# how to solve error "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'day'" in django application

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I noticed this error in my application, "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'day'". What I have noticed about it is that. I have a model named course_schedule, the course schedule has an option of Monday to Sunday. If the course schedule is partially populated, that is I populate only some days, like 3 days out of the complete 7 days in a week, I get the error but whenever I populate the course schedule populate course schedule model completely, I don't have the error and everything works well.

error log:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Habib\Documents\django\FIVERR\Ayyub_SMS\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\Habib\Documents\django\FIVERR\Ayyub_SMS\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Habib\Documents\django\FIVERR\Ayyub_SMS\sms\schoolapp\views.py", line 1754, in sir_course
    get_all = getall(2021, sch.day)

Exception Type: AttributeError at /en/sir_course
Exception Value: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'day'
```

models.py

```
class Assign_teacher_to_courses(models.Model):
    Course_Name = models.ForeignKey(add_courses, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Teacher_Name = models.ForeignKey(add_teacher_by_manager, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Course_Name.Course_Name+" - "+self.Teacher_Name.teacher_ID+" - "+self.Teacher_Name.teacher_name

class course_schedule(models.Model):

    days_choices = (
        ("Mon", 'Monday'),
        ("Tue", 'Tuesday'),
        ('Wed', "Wednessday"),
        ('Thurs', "Thursday"),
        ('Fri', "Friday"),
        ('Sat', "Saturday"),
        ("Sun", "Sunday"),
    )

    day = models.CharField(max_length=60, default="Sun")
    time_session = models.CharField(max_length=150, default='8:00am')
    end_session = models.CharField(max_length=150, default='10:00am')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.day
```

views.py

```
def sir_course(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        get_course_name_th = Assign_teacher_to_courses.objects.filter(Teacher_Name=get_id_teach)
        # print(get_course_name_th)

        store_email_teacher_dtta = store_email_teach_new.objects.filter(Teacher_ID=teach_course_id)

        days = {}

        for course in get_course_name_th:

            # print(course.Course_Name.syllabus)

            sch = course_schedule.objects.get(id=course.Course_Name.pk)

            get_all = getall(2021, sch.day)

            lists = {}
            for n in get_all:

                date = n.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")

                try:
                    if days[str(date)]:

                        days[str(date)].append(str(course.Course_Name.Course_Name)+" "+str(course.Course_Name.course_code))

                except KeyError:

                    days[str(date)] = [str(course.Course_Name.Course_Name)+" "+str(course.Course_Name.course_code),]

        # print(days)

        context1 = {'get_course_name_t_cours':get_course_name_th, "days": days}

        return render(request, 'teacher_page.html', context1)

    else:
        return redirect('/')
```

Comment: Make sure `sch` is not `None`?

Comment: okay, i am testing it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66640240/7395911) snippet of your `add_courses` model.

```
class add_courses(models.Model):
    Course_Name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    Manager_Name = models.ForeignKey(Manager_login_information, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(default='', blank=True)
    syllabus = models.TextField(default='', blank=True)
    student = models.ManyToManyField(add_students_by_manager, blank=True)
    schedule = models.ForeignKey(course_schedule, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Course_Name
```

You have the following relationship path from `Assign_teacher_to_courses` to `course_schedule`:

```
Assign_teacher_to_courses -> add_courses -> course_schedule
```

Therefore to get the schedule of each `course` in `get_course_name_th` you should change `sch = course_schedule.objects.get(id=course.Course_Name.pk)` to `sch = course.Course_Name.schedule`.

Comment: Thanks for the solution.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like maybe sch is None.

You should always put your object get in a try...except block or you can use the inbuilt `get_object_or_404`